# Can custom fields be added without a meta box?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I'm building a custom post type entry screen (in code).  I would like to have my fields display without a meta box surrounding them, so that they look more like the user profile page. Is that possible, without using a third-party plugin?

Is `add_meta_box()` the only way to display fields on an admin area post entry/edit screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove border on custom meta box](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87339/remove-border-on-custom-meta-box)

Comment: Sooo.... it sounds like there's no "WordPress Way" other than adding meta boxes?

Comment: You tried the answer in the above comment?

Comment: I'm sure that would work - it just seems like there ought to be a built-in PHP way to do it, without needing to bring in jQuery.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in functions.php

```
add_action('admin_init', 'wpse_87339_admin_init');
function wpse_87339_admin_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script('wpse_87339_admin', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js', array('jquery'));
}
```

and create new js file name admin.js and then add the below code in it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Remove all .postbox classes from sidebar
    $('#side-sortables .postbox').removeClass('postbox');

    // Remove .postbox from specific metabox (page attributes)
    $('#pageparentdiv').removeClass('postbox');
});
```

Comment: Please properly format your posts

Comment: And don't copy your answers from [other posts](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87339/remove-border-on-custom-meta-box).